# align icons on table row android

Tags: android, icons, alignment, tablerow

Hello i am having problems to align 2 icons and text view in center of the icons . 
actually the first icon and the text are align properly but the last icon "playIcon" is not aligned.I want him in the right corner.. all aligned.
this is what i have [image]

--

### this is my XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="3"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="TODO" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/playbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

             />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RelativeLayout for align images in left and right.
Something like this code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/img2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Test"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Use android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" for left image and android:layout_alignParentRight="true" for right image. also use android:layout_centerVertical="true" for both of them.

I hope this code will be useful